# How to overcome Method calls Thread.sleep() with a lock held warning in findbugs?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, findbugs

I have the following synchronized method which is used to shut down the task manager. The logic is to check for active tasks and if there is any, I will wait for 1 second and will check again.

But it seems like find bugs plugin is not allowing me to use Thread.sleep() inside a synchronized block and giving the following warning

> Method calls Thread.sleep() with a lock held
>   This method calls Thread.sleep() with a lock held. This may result in very poor performance and scalability, or a deadlock, since other threads may be waiting to acquire the lock. It is a much better idea to call wait() on the lock, which releases the lock and allows other threads to run.

Any idea on how to overcome this issue ?

```
public synchronized void stop() {

    // try to wait a bit for task shutdown
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (activeTaskCount == 0) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
    }


    if (activeTaskCount > 0) {
        log.warn("Unable to shutdown all polling tasks of " + jmsConsumerName);
    }

    if (JMSTaskManagerState != STATE_FAILURE) {
        JMSTaskManagerState = STATE_STOPPED;
    }
    log.info("Task manager for jms consumer " + receiveTimeout + " shutdown");
}
```

Comment: move the sleep to a separate method?

Comment: @ScaryWombat It clears the warning, but still what good it will do ? there is no difference in moving the sleep to a separate method right?

Comment: Why not follow the warning message and replace sleep(1000) with wait(1000)?

Comment: @sambaheerathan It is your logic.  If it is necessary then it is necessary

Comment: It seems like you are polling in the same Thread as you are sleeping, that would indeed be a bug, the polling (with the sleep) should be done in a separate thread. Written like this, it will block everything. So to overcome this issue, put the polling in a separate thread that calls the synchronised method every second to see if all tasks are completed.

Comment: Who is supposed to change `activeTaskCount`? To make this work, the modifying thread must hold the same lock, which is exactly why sleeping while holding the lock is broken. As @Lidae already pointed out, you should use `wait` instead and the thread modifying `activeTaskCount` should acquire the lock (i.e. execute a `synchronized` method on the same object which will) modify the variable and call `notify`).

Comment: Just to be clear: the loop you have written, is semantically equivalent to `if(activeTaskCount != 0) sleep(5000);`